# Format cell as minutes for use in time calculation?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, timestamp

I have 4 columns: `Time In`, `Lunch`, `Time Out` and `Daily Total`.  The Daily Total column uses the following formula:

`=([Time Out]-[Time In])-[Lunch]`

I want to be able to simply enter minutes for the Lunch field.  What format does the cell need to be for the formula above to work?

I've tried [mm] but when I type "42" it changes it to 60480.  I've tried a regular number, but then the formula fails.  I've tried various time formats but then typing 42 changes it to 0:00 and the formula bar says '2/11/1900 12:00:00 AM'.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mm` is correct to format for minutes, or `[mm]` if you want it to go over 60 as needed.

However, you need to enter your data *in days*, as all date/time in Excel is handled in days. So, 30 minutes are 1/2*1/24 day, which is about 0.020833. If you enter that, it will show '30'.

Now that might not be very convenient, but it is the only way to *really* work with minutes. Another option is to *fake* it, and format the cell as `0" min"`. that way, Excel considers it a normal number, but shows it with " min" behind the number, which makes every human read it as minutes.

The only disadvantage is if you want to do *calculations* with it, at that time, you need to remember that it is just a number and not really in minutes, so if you use it in formulas, you need to divide it by the factor between minutes and days (24*60) - or keep faking the unit with formats.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now using this formula: `=(D3-C3)-(E3/(24*60))` and have E3 formatted as a number so I can easily type in the minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Format the `Time in` and `Time out` columns as `Time` and the `Lunch` and `Daily Total` columns as `h:mm`.

[image]

Enter the lunch minutes like this: `0:30`. Excel will recognize that as minutes. Now the calculation will work.

[image]